# Is oauth 2.0 access_token IP dependant or not?

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, oauth, vk

I wonder whether access_token provided by Facebook, Twitter or Vkontakte API depends on IP of requester or not.

I have checked this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth but it says nothing about IP.

Might it be vendor-implementation dependent or there is some strict regulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nops, they are not IP dependant. they are just application specific. if you have access token for certain application, you can use the same with that application from any IP address, even from your local server.

Comment: thanks for reply! any proof link, so I can accept the answer?

Comment: I replied so because for my facebook application I store user's access token in db and i am able to query their facebook even from my local server while testing something. btw for your proof link, i searched a little and got this thread, have a look [oauth token security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105364/oauth-token-security)

Comment: Read the RFC, it’s linked in the Wikipedia article ;-)

Comment: thanks Smita, I believe you are right. Can we discuss more on FB? I was told by friend that they might be IP-dependant without any proof, so started to doubt..

Comment: sure, no problem. what else you want to discuss?

Comment: Paste an access token into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token and you will see the fields of data that it encapsulates & represents

Comment: James, this is a very useful link. Thanks

Comment: @Smita, do you have any idea how to integrate Facebook chat in Java desktop application?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov sorry No, i havn't worked with facebook java api ever. you can ask as question here, many people might be knowing.

Comment: @Smita, btw, I am working Russian social network Vkontakte now, and appears that they do issue IP-dependant access_token: "{"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address."

Comment: oh, then they may have. I have worked on facebook, LinkedIn an twitter API these doesnt give IP dependant tokens.